# On Ubuntu 22.04 LTS does doing a minimal install affect the ability of the OS to boot using X?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, xorg

I recently did a minimal install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS which installed without error.  I have installed a number of apps, one of which doesn't seem to play well with Wayland (Bluemail).  So I logged out then chose Ubuntu on X and logged in.  It starts to login then reverts back to the login window - never logging into the OS.
My question is - does doing a minimal install not install all X components?

Comment: "*reverts back to the login window*" is a classic symptom of a crash. Check your logs.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, I found that the type of install (minimal vs full) does not affect the system's ability to run Xorg or Wayland.  I confirmed this by cloning my hard drive to a USB drive and booting that drive on a system with an older processor, GPU and BIOS version and it worked perfectly (I was able to run both Wayland and X) despite the fact that it was a minimal install.
I eventually found that my issue was actually that the drivers for my GPU (an NVidia RTX 2060 Super) were preventing my system from running Xorg.  By downloading and installing the latest drivers.  I was able to resolve this by updating the NVidia drivers.